# Using Child of Generic c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I've got an abstract Generic class, defined like this

```
abstract public class X<T>
```

which is instantiated with a set of children of a common ancestor, ie

```
public class Y : X<Bar>
public class Z : X<Baz>
```

where Bar and Baz are children of Foo. Is there a way to create a class

```
public class W : X<Foo>
```

so that I can store W, X, Y, Z in an object such as

```
A<Foo>
```

?

EDIT:
Just to point out, I'm not in a position to change the underlying structure. My choices are either implement this in such a way that I can do this, or create a separate, duplicate class for all children of Foo.

Comment: Have you considered using an interface?

Comment: Can you have them all inherit from an interface, so T can be marked as covariant?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I can't change the definition of X, unfortunately.

Comment: @MikyDinescu Sorry, my bad. OO terminology isn't my forte, and I'm struggling with this problem so I messed it up. Although my terminology is incorrect I think my point was gotten across?

Comment: @MikyDinescu "Saying that a class is a child of another class usually means that the latter contains the former in a "has a" relationship" Oh really? Learn what "child" means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subclass_%28computer_science%29#Subclasses_and_superclasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  What you're asking for is for these types to be covariant with respect to this generic argument.  The generic arguments of classes can *never* be covariant.  The generic arguments of *interfaces* can *potentially* be covariant, if the interface is defined as being covariant and the generic argument is only ever used in a manor ensuring that all such programs can be statically verified of being type safe.

Comment: So changing the decleration of X to be an interface would let me do it? I can't do that, unfortunately, I have no control over the decleration of X.

Comment: @maccard It's not the *only* change that you would need to make, but you would certainly need to make that change in order to allow for this behavior.  What other changes would need to be made would be dependent on what is actually going on here, and whether X's API is inherently covariant with respect to `T`.  It may or may not be.

Comment: Alright, well I guess that's that. Not gonna happen. Time for a new solution. Thanks!

Comment: If treating `Y`, `Z` and `W` in a unified way makes sense, then extracting a covariant interface should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing and using a covariant interface `IX<T, TBase>` you can do this.

```
public class Foo { }

public class Bar : Foo { }   
public class Baz : Foo { }

public interface IX<out T, TBase> where T : TBase { }

public abstract class X<T, TBase> : IX<T, TBase> where T : TBase { }

public class Y : X<Bar, Foo> { }
public class Z : X<Baz, Foo> { }
public class W : X<Foo, Foo> { }
```

Now the following code is valid.

```
IX<Foo, Foo> x;

x = new Y();
x = new Z();
x = new W();
```

If `TBase` is fixed you can of course get rid of the second type parameter `TBase` and just use `Foo` directly. Anyway, the interesting part is extracting the covariant interface `IX<T, TBase>` which might not be easy but should be possible.